# At what point should I worry about underflow in numpy values?

Tags: python, numpy, underflow

I am doing calculations with Python numpy. Here is a resulting numpy array:

```
[  5.15054786e-11   5.15251385e-11   5.15262922e-11 ...,   5.21100674e-11
5.21097550e-11   5.21088179e-11]
```

Those are pretty tiny. At what point should I worry about underflow in my calculations? These need to be ultra-precise. Is there a definite value range to worry about, or perhaps a reference which states this value?

Comment: The answer depends on the type of your data. `float` and `double` have different precissions, but for `1e-11` both should work without problems.

Comment: If you're concerned about underflow, you can use `np.seterr` to warn/raise when underflow is encountered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smallest representable [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number_(computing)) in a 64 bit floating point number is:

```
>>> 2**-1022
2.2250738585072014e-308
```

That range can be extended a little more using [denormal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), which take the smallest down to:

```
>>> 2**(-1022 - 52)
5e-324
```

But:

```
>>> 2**(-1022 - 53)
0.0
```

Another relevant small number (again for 64 bit numbers) would be:

```
>>> 2**-52
2.220446049250313e-16
```

because:

```
>>> 1 + 2**-52
1.0000000000000002
```

but:

```
>>> 1 + 2**-53
1.0
```