# Numpy array multiplication leads to some values being inf even though the original arrays are all valid floats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to perform an element wise multiplication of numerous numpy arrays.

The implementation:-

```
mult = np.ones(len(single_arrays[0]))
for i in range(len(single_arrays)):
    mult *= single_arrays[i]
```

Most values in the each of the single arrays is between 0 and 1(some values are above 1), and the 2D "single_arrays" has about 700 individual arrays.

The resultant array "mult" has a lot of "inf" values and one "nan" value even though no array in the "single_arrays" has "inf" or "nan" values, all the values are valid floating points.

Why is this issue arising in mult ? Some values are very small in the array, going to tens and thousandths decimal places, could underflow or overflow be an issue here ?

Comment: Based in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34930570/at-what-point-should-i-worry-about-underflow-in-numpy-values) you can use [numpy.seterr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) to raise an exception if underflow occurs.

Comment: Please provide us with `single_arrays`

Answer (score 1):

If everything you said is correct, it can't happen. Therefore something you believe isn't true :-)

`*` can only deliver an infinity if a multiplicand is an inf, or the product is very large. But it can't be large if it's true that "all values in the each of the single arrays is between 0 and 1". Then no product can be larger than 1.0.

`*` can only deliver a NaN if a multiplicand is a NaN, or you try to multiply (in either order) an inf and a zero. Which you say you're never doing either.

Underflow is certainly possible, but is irrelevant - tiny numbers can't produce an inf unless you're dividing by a zero, or a very small number (close to 0, in the denormal range).

So add prints to find out what's actually happening. Pick an index `j` for which `mult[j]` ends up with an inf, then change the code to show you where it came from:

```py
for i in range(len(single_arrays)):
    orig = mult[j]
    mult *= single_arrays[i]
    if mult[j] == inf:
        print("got an inf in mult[j]",
              "as the product of",
              orig, "and", single_arrays[i][j])
        assert False  # just a way to raise an exception
```

Try that and tell us what happens.

Comment: Hey @Tim nice to see your answer. I am a fan of your Zen of Python!